# iPhone iPad Not detecting the browser type in ASP.Net MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, safari

I have a web application which has alot of widgests/page in it. Certain widgets I want to block when opened in Safari and display some sort of message if anyone tries to open the webapp from Safari browser.
Below is the code I have written.

```
  public class BlockFromSafari : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        // runs just before the action is executed
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var browserType = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser;
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            if (browserType.Contains("Safari"))
            {
                // Redirect the user accordingly
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Security" }, { "action", "Safari" } });
            }
        }
    }
```

Kindly note that I have applied this filter on the all the Action Method which I want

```
  public ActionResult Safari()
  {
            return Content("This is SAFARI!!");
  }
```

Current Behaviour:

1. If I open the website and visit the corresponding URL, in Chrome in *WindowsPC* page opens fine, where as if I open in Safari Browser in Windows PC I get redirected to "This is SAFARI content page".
2. If I open the website and visit the corresponding URL, in Chrome in *Mac PC* page opens fine, where as if I open in Safari Browser in Mac PC I get redirected to "This is SAFARI content page"

So far so good.
Now here is the problem

Issue: If I open the website and visit the corresponding URL, in **Chrome** in *Mobile device* or *Ipad* page still displays "This is SAFARI" ideally I expected the same behaviour as in PC. Please guide me.

**Expected Behaviour:**

Mobile Device-Chrome - Should open fine

Mobeil Devive-Safari - "This is SAFARI" should be displayed

**Interesting Read** [Chrome Treated as Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599548/why-iphone-treating-google-chrome-as-safari-also-mozilla-firefox-as-safari-brows)

Answer (score 0):

So wear, this article probably will help you
https://51degrees.com/blog/mobile-and-tablet-device-detection-with-mvc5

1. The main idea is to get Browser information from headers, something like:

   `requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Profiles.SelectMany(p => p.Values).ToArray();`

So you could add another conditional if it's mobile.

2. Another aproach is to use JavaScript and redirect if its mobile, like:

   `var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
   if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
    // iPad or iPhone
   }
   else {
   // Anything else
   }`
   here is the full answer([Determine if user navigated from mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007480/determine-if-user-navigated-from-mobile-safari))